# Does there exist a non-trivial elementary embedding from an ultrapower $V^{I}/U$ to $V^{I}/U$?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Does there exist a set $I$ and an ultrafilter $U$ on $I$ and a non-trivial elementary embedding $j:V^{I}/U\rightarrow V^{I}/U$?

So the Kunen inconsistency result states that there does not exist a non-trivial elementary embedding $j:V\rightarrow V$. Similarly, for each ultrafilter $U$ on $I$, there exists a structure $\mathcal{X}$ (here $\mathcal{X}$ has uncountably many function symbols and uncountably any relation symbols) where there does not exist a non-trivial elementary embedding $e:\mathcal{X}^{I}/U\rightarrow \mathcal{X}^{I}/U$. I am wondering if one can put these impossibility results together.

Comment: One special case you have mentioned above is that if $U$ is an ultrafilter, there is no nontrivial elementary embedding $k : M_U\to M_U$ such that $k\circ j_U = j_U$.

Here is another special case. Assume $V = \text{HOD}$. In this context, working in NBG, an observation due to Woodin is that if $j_0,j_1 : V\to M$ are elementary embeddings from the universe into the same inner model, then $j_0 = j_1$. Suppose now that $U$ is a countably complete ultrafilter. If $k : M_U\to M_U$ is elementary, then $k\circ j_U = j_U$ by Woodin's observation, so $k$ is the identity by the other case.

Comment: I wonder if one can have an elementary embedding $j:V_{\lambda}^{I}/U\rightarrow V_{\lambda}^{I}/U$ where $\lambda$ is a cardinal with $\mathrm{cf}(\lambda)>|I|$.

Comment: Another possible generalized question. Does there exist an ultrafilter $U$ on a set $I$ where if $M=V_{\lambda}^{I}/U$, then there is a generic ultrafilter $G$ and an elementary embedding $j:M[G]\rightarrow M[G]$?